# Can i use microphone in Corona?

Tags: android, audio, real-time, coronasdk

I'm new to programming and I want to create an app. I have to use the phone's microphone in real time to implement it.
Since I have only used enviroments that i have been told in class I don't know what to use now. I have tried using corona but i heard that it doesn't implement audio (i'm not 100% sure about this).Is this true? (I am programming in Windows 8)

If i can't,what enviroment do you recommend that i should use? I only need the intensity of the voice i don't need full voice recognition. 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Check [this](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/media/newRecording.html).

Comment: mobile phones can run a browser where you can execute Web Audio API which can easily listen to the microphone ... its not an app however it will give you the audio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Corona audio API](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/media/audioSystem/index.html) only support audio playing, and does not give access to the microphone.
To support the microphone in your app, you can create a native plugin and integrate it using [Corona Native](https://docs.coronalabs.com/native/android/index.html)